# Python, running command line tools in parallel

Tags: python, shell, command-line, parallel-processing

I am using Python as a script language to do some data processing and call command-line tools for number crunching. I wish to run command-line tools in parallel since they are independent with each other. When one command-line tool is finished, I can collect its results from the output file. So I also need some synchronization mechanism to notify my main Python program that one task is finished so that the result could be parsed into my main program.

Currently, I use `os.system()`, which works fine for one-thread, but cannot be parallelized.

Thanks!

Comment: Python has good support for [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) and [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html). What is the specific problem you have with those?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `Pool` object from the `multiprocessing` module. You can then use e.g. `Pool.map()` to do parallel processing. An example would be my markphotos script (see below), where a function is called multiple times in parallel to each process a picture.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Adds my copyright notice to photos.
#
# Author: R.F. Smith <rsmith@xs4all.nl>
# $Date: 2012-10-28 17:00:24 +0100 $
#
# To the extent possible under law, Roland Smith has waived all copyright and
# related or neighboring rights to markphotos.py. This work is published from
# the Netherlands. See http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/

import sys
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock
from os import utime, devnull
import os.path
from time import mktime

globallock = Lock() 

def processfile(name):
    """Adds copyright notice to the file.

    Arguments:
    name -- file to modify
    """
    args = ['exiftool', '-CreateDate', name]
    createdate = subprocess.check_output(args)
    fields = createdate.split(":") #pylint: disable=E1103
    year = int(fields[1])
    cr = "R.F. Smith <rsmith@xs4all.nl> http://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/"
    cmt = "Copyright © {} {}".format(year, cr)
    args = ['exiftool', '-Copyright="Copyright (C) {} {}"'.format(year, cr),
            '-Comment="{}"'.format(cmt), '-overwrite_original', '-q', name]
    rv = subprocess.call(args)
    modtime = int(mktime((year, int(fields[2]), int(fields[3][:2]),
                          int(fields[3][3:]), int(fields[4]), int(fields[5]),
                          0,0,-1)))
    utime(name, (modtime, modtime))
    globallock.acquire()
    if rv == 0:
        print "File '{}' processed.".format(name)
    else:
        print "Error when processing file '{}'".format(name)
    globallock.release()

def checkfor(args):
    """Make sure that a program necessary for using this script is
    available.

    Arguments:
    args -- list of commands to pass to subprocess.call.
    """
    if isinstance(args, str):
        args = args.split()
    try:
        with open(devnull, 'w') as f:
            subprocess.call(args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=f)
    except:
        print "Required program '{}' not found! exiting.".format(args[0])
        sys.exit(1)

def main(argv):
    """Main program.

    Arguments:
    argv -- command line arguments
    """
    if len(argv) == 1:
        binary = os.path.basename(argv[0])
        print "Usage: {} [file ...]".format(binary)
        sys.exit(0)
    checkfor(['exiftool',  '-ver'])
    p = Pool()
    p.map(processfile, argv[1:])
    p.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thanks! and it seems that at each process, I can use `os.system` to call my command-line?

Comment: Better use `subprocess` for that. See the linked example.

Comment: @RolandSmith - could you restore the link to markphotos or add the source here?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to run commandline tools as separate processes, just use `os.system` (or better: The `subprocess` module) to start them asynchronously. On Unix/linux/macos:

```
subprocess.call("command -flags arguments &", shell=True)
```

On Windows:

```
subprocess.call("start command -flags arguments", shell=True)
```

As for knowing when a command has finished: Under unix you could get set up with `wait` etc., but if you're writing the commandline scripts, I'd just have them write a message into a file, and monitor the file from the calling python script.

@James Youngman proposed a solution to your second question: Synchronization. If you want to control your processes from python, you could start them asynchronously with Popen.

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen("command1 -flags arguments")
p2 = subprocess.Popen("command2 -flags arguments")
```

Beware that if you use Popen and your processes write a lot of data to stdout, your program will deadlock. Be sure to redirect all output to a log file.

`p1` and `p2` are objects that you can use to keep tabs on your processes. `p1.poll()` will not block, but will return None if the process is still running. It will return the exit status when it is done, so you can check if it is zero.

```
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    for proc in [p1, p2]:
        status = proc.poll()
        if status == None:
            continue
        elif status == 0:
            # harvest the answers
        else:
            print "command1 failed with status", status
```

The above is just a model: As written, it will never exit, and it will keep "harvesting" the results of completed processes. But I trust you get the idea.

Comment: The test would be more general and concise as `if any(p.wait() for p in [p1, p2]):…`.

Comment: Guys, the OP wants to run computations asynchronously and harvest the results. He wants a way "to notify my main Python program that one task is finished". wait() will block until all children are finished.

Comment: @James Youngman: Sorry for rolling back your changes. I did not expect them to disappear from history. I included them in the answer (as you can see, it's a separate solution with separate issues).

Comment: We don't know that, and @Yin talked about "one task" being finished. I could imagine lots of use cases: Maybe he's limiting the number of jobs to run in parallel at once, and needs to start the next one; or completed jobs just get entered into a database; or this is a print server and it should pop up a notification as soon as a job is done; or whatever.